# How to extract and sum xml attribute values in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a lot of large xml messages stored as CLOBs in a column **xml_message** in table **online_message**. For example the messages looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CustomerDetails xmlns="http://something.com/version/1.0">
<CustomerId>100345</CustomerId>
<AccountDetails Account="account1" Value="103"/>
<AccountDetails Account="account2" Value="142"/>
<AccountDetails Account="account3" Value="345"/>
<AccountDetails Account="account4" Value="634"/>
</CustomerDetails>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CustomerDetails xmlns="http://something.com/version/1.0">
<CustomerId>100465</CustomerId>
<AccountDetails Account="account5" Value="198"/>
<AccountDetails Account="account6" Value="567"/>
<AccountDetails Account="account7" Value="1984"/>
<AccountDetails Account="account8" Value="84"/>
</CustomerDetails>
```

I want to get all the **Value** attributes in all xml messages and sum them up. So the final result (in this example) should be 103+142+345+634+198+567+1984+84=4057. Any idea how i can do this in sql developer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
SELECT sum(t.v) 
FROM online_message, XMLTABLE('for $i in //*/@Value return $i' 
  PASSING online_message.xml_message 
  COLUMNS v NUMBER PATH '.') t
;
```

Comment: I got the following error:
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.

Comment: Do "xml_message" CLOBs contain _multiple_ XML documents?

Answer (score 0):

here is a related method - you can try to edit for your purposes.

```
select Sum(
         to_number(
            extractvalue(
               xmltype(
                  dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C'))) count
from user_tables;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit confused as i'm new to both sql and xml. What table does **table_name** refer to and what is **c**? What should i write instead of /ROWSET/ROW/C?